# Is it possible to hide #VALUE! in a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In A1, I input 1,2,3,4 and so on.

B1 remains blank because this is where I will enter a number (qty).

C1's content is:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,'Item ID'!$A$4:$E$11166,3,FALSE)),"",(VLOOKUP(A1,'Item ID'!$A$4:$E$11166,3,FALSE)))
```

It will also show a number

Then, my problem is D1, which shows #VALUE! D1 content is:

```
=B1*C1
```

Is it possible to hide that #VALUE? I have already conducted some research and it has not produced an answer.  The information I have found seems to say it is impossible because I have a lot of special characters. Is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap it with `IFERROR()`.

You can make your cell D1 as `=IFERROR(B1*C1, 0)` which will make D1 as 0 instead of #VALUE.  Otherwise `=IFERROR(B1*C1, "")` will make it blank in place of #VALUE.

Comment: Your suggestion worked|! :) Thank you so much! :)